# What is the point of `interface class` in Dart 3?

Tags: dart, class, oop, interface, mixins

I have been playing around with Dart 3 a bit and am a fan of the new class modifiers. But one I can't seem to get my head around: why does `interface class` exist? I understand `interface mixin` because you can declare abstract members. But you can't do that with an `interface class`, at least in the latest alpha.

Specifically, you can do this:

```dart
interface mixin A {
  void foo();
}

abstract class B {
  void bar();
}
```

But you can't do this:

```dart
interface class C {
  void foobar(); // compilation error: needs a concrete implementation
}
```

What is the point of having an `interface class` where you will always need provide stub implementations and then implement them later on? When should you use an `interface class` over `interface mixin`?

Comment: You can use an `interface` class if you want a class to be constructible, implementable, but not extendable.  If you don't want it to be constructible, then use an `abstract interface class`.  There's [a helpful table in the feature specification](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/master/accepted/future-releases/class-modifiers/feature-specification.md#syntax).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This](https://medium.com/@kvenn/dart-3-0-best-new-features-why-you-should-care-429e739f2690) article covers a bit more details. And [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76266385/1759443) answers it more broadly.

But the summary is, I agree with you, and that's why you should use `abstract interface` instead of just `interface`. You'd only use `interface` over `abstract interface` if you wanted to be able to instantiate it.

#### abstract interface

**What is it**: More like a traditional interface. Can only be implemented (not extended). But you can define functions without bodies.

**Why you should care**: You can define just the “shape” without defining any functionality. There’s nothing hidden in the parent class.

```dart
// -- File a.dart
abstract interface class AbstractInterfaceClass {
  String name = 'Dave'; // Allowed
  void body() { print('body'); } // Allowed
  
  // This is a more traditional implementation
  int get myField; // Allowed
  void noBody(); // Allowed
}

// -- File b.dart
// Not allowed
class ExtensionClass extends AbstractInterfaceClass{}
// Allowed
class ConcreteClass implements AbstractInterfaceClass {
  // Have to override everything
  @override
  String name = 'ConcreteName';
  @override
  void body() { print('body'); }

  @override
  int get myField => 5;
  @override
  void noBody() => print('concreteBody');
}
```

#### vs interface

```dart
// -- File a.dart
interface class InterfaceClass {
  String name = 'Dave'; // Allowed
  void body() { print('body'); } // Allowed

  int get myField; // Not allowed
  void noBody(); // Not allowed
}

// -- File b.dart
// Not allowed
class ExtensionClass extends InterfaceClass{}
// Allowed
class ConcreteClass implements InterfaceClass{
  // Have to override everything
  @override
  String name = 'ConcreteName';
  @override
  void body() { print('body'); }
}
```

Comment: If body() must be overridden in the concrete class then what's the point in  providing a default implementation if it can't be used by the concrete class?

Comment: In the `abstract interface` + `implements` case, it does nothing. But you can also `extend` an `abstract interface` which allows you to call `super.body()` to add shared functionality into the super class. I wish they had a different keyword...but that's Dart.