# How do the new class modifiers work in Dart 3.0 (interface vs abstract)?

Tags: flutter, dart

They added a few new modifiers to classes. What is the difference between abstract class, interface, and abstract interface?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [official docs](https://dart.dev/language/class-modifiers#sealed) are pretty thorough, but here's super short summary. For a longer summary, check out the bottom of [this post](https://medium.com/@kvenn/dart-3-0-best-new-features-why-you-should-care-429e739f2690).

The first thing you need to get is the difference between implements and extends. These concepts existed in Dart 2.x, but get expanded on.

`implements` = Your sub-class has the exact same “shape” (fields/functions) as the parent class but must define all its own behavior. You do not inherit any functionality from the parent's functions or fields. It’s similar to other languages, but you can implement just about any class (regardless of modifier)

`extends` = Your sub-class can extend (override) behavior, inherit behavior, and implement behavior

Then this table summarizes the differences:
[image]

Here is the full table from [the spec](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/main/accepted/future-releases/class-modifiers/feature-specification.md#syntax):

| Declaration | Construct? | Extend? | Implement? | Mix in? | Exhaustive? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `class` | **Yes** | **Yes** | **Yes** | No | No |
| `base class` | **Yes** | **Yes** | No | No | No |
| `interface class` | **Yes** | No | **Yes** | No | No |
| `final class` | **Yes** | No | No | No | No |
| `sealed class` | No | No | No | No | **Yes** |
| `abstract class` | No | **Yes** | **Yes** | No | No |
| `abstract base class` | No | **Yes** | No | No | No |
| `abstract interface class` | No | No | **Yes** | No | No |
| `abstract final class` | No | No | No | No | No |
| `mixin class` | **Yes** | **Yes** | **Yes** | **Yes** | No |
| `base mixin class` | **Yes** | **Yes** | No | **Yes** | No |
| `abstract mixin class` | No | **Yes** | **Yes** | **Yes** | No |
| `abstract base mixin class` | No | **Yes** | No | **Yes** | No |
| `mixin` | No | No | **Yes** | **Yes** | No |
| `base mixin` | No | No | No | **Yes** | No |

Comment: It'd be better if this table were text instead of an image.  There's also the table from [the feature specification](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/main/accepted/future-releases/class-modifiers/feature-specification.md#syntax) although it has different rows and columns.

Comment: Nice! I had seen that but liked the simpler version. But for the sake of being exhaustive, how about I include both.